# How to tell that an entire function approaches zero along the real line

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, soft-question

Suppose $f(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ has infinite radius of convergence (where the $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$).  Is there any tests which can be done on the sequence $\{a_n\}$ to determine whether $f$ converges to zero along the real line?  That is, whether $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$?

Necessary or sufficient conditions are welcome.

Comment: No universal test for all entire functions.  Furthermore, even for such a special case as the polynomials of degree 5 or higher, there is no universal formula for locating the zeros (and, accordingly, testing whether they lie on the real line).  This is nonexistence is the content of Abel's Theorem: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/abel.pdf

Comment: Do you mean "wether $f\color{red}{(z)}$ converges to 0 for all $z\in\mathbb C$"?

Comment: @avs I am familiar with Abel's Theorem, but I do not actually care about the location of the zeros, only the limit along the real line.

Comment: @sranthrop Thanks for the question, I updated to make it clear.

Comment: @TrevorRichards, Your question can be phrased as follows: Is the real line a subset if the set of zeros of $f$?  If we knew all the zeros of $f$, we would be able to answer your question.

Comment: @avs: $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$ is not equivalent with $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @sranthrop, sorry, I misread the previous version of the question.

Comment: Of course any test for the question as currently stated would have to be sensitive to **every coefficient**, making it very unlike the ratio and root tests.  A weakening would be, can we give criterion for $\{a_n\}$ such that some derivative of $f$ approaches zero along $\mathbb{R}$, or such that $f-p$ approaches zero along $\mathbb{R}$ for some polynomial $p$.

Comment: Certainly there is no test involving just the absolute values of the coefficients that is sufficient to give the conclusion.